# How to remove all files from directory without removing the directory in Deno?

Tags: javascript, deno

How to remove all files from a directory without removing the directory itself using Deno?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily with the [`fs`](https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts) module:

```js
import * as fs from "https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts";
await fs.emptyDir("path/to/dir");
```

It's also possible to iterate the files for some finer control without using the [`fs`](https://deno.land/std/fs/mod.ts) module:

```js
import * as path from "https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts";

const dirPath = path.join("path", "to", "dir"); // “path/to/dir”
for await(const dirEntry of Deno.readDir(dirPath)) {
    await Deno.remove(path.join(dirPath, dirEntry.name), { recursive: true });
}
```

Requires `--allow-read` and `--allow-write` permissions, in any case.